# How set proxy auth in e2e?

Tags: angular, proxy, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I need help with auth in proxy with my e2e protractor.
A part of my `protractor.conf.js`:

```
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    proxy: {
      proxyType: 'manual',
      httpProxy: 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:port',
   }
  },
```

That's work fine, but my chrome open a dialog window for request a proxy credentials.
How I can avoid it? I want set auth in protractor.conf or other angular file.

Comment: Could you please try by providing proxy credentials in browser.get itself. Ex. "https://username:password@your_url".

Comment: That was don't work for me. ;(